# How do I delete a matching line, the lines above and those below  in the section?

Tags: linux, shell, regex, sed

In nagios config

```
define service{
          use                 generic-service
          host_name           xxx.xxx.com
          service_description xxx Status
          check_command       check_http!xxx.xxx.com -S
          }
```

I want to delete the entire section as given above matching regex **xxx.xxx.com** . How to do it using **sed** or any other Linux utility

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an awk script like this:

awk -f this-script.awk my-nagios.conf > my-nagios.conf.new

```
# start of block
/^define/ {
  collecting = 1;
  matched = 0;
  buf = "";
}

# end of block
/}/ {
   collecting = 0;
   if (!matched) {
     print buf $0;
   };
   next;
}

# Row in bad block
/xxx.abc.com/ {
  if (collecting)
    matched = 1;
}

# Normal row
{
  if (collecting) {
    buf = buf $0 "\n";
  } else {
    print $0;
  }
}
```

Comment: The awk script collects rows of the {} block into a variable and only prints if out on the end of the block if /xxx.abc.com/ is not matched.

Answer (score 1):

```
ed my-nagios.conf <<q
w my-bagios.conf~
g/xxx.xxx.com/ ?define?,/}/d
w
q
```